# Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid (error when i use Navigator tag)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobile, components, navigator

i'm facing this issue when i tried to run the example code about Navigator tag from React-Native docs.

This is my App.js file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import  { Navigator } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Navigator 
      initialRoute={{title: 'Awesome Scene', index: 0}}
      renderScene={(route, navigator) => <Text>Hello {route.title}!</Text>}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

And this is my index.js file:

```
/**
 * @format
 */

import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

And this is the problem:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that react-native has deprecated `Navigator`, so you're most likely using a version that doesn't support it, I believe version 0.46 supports it but the most recent versions do not.

I would recommend you take a look at [react navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/)

[React Native 0.61 Documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.61/activityindicator) Here you can see on the left that there's no Navigator.

Comment: I have imported Text component but the error is still remain. This error only appear when i use Navigator tag.

Comment: @PhatTran what version of react-native are you using?

Comment: I'm using 0.61.5

Comment: OK, Thanks you so much for the help. I will check it out.

Comment: Sure thing, don't forget to upvote and mark answer as correct if it solves your problem :)